# Animated side navigation menu: How to avoid jumping layout?

Tags: animation, menu, css-animations, user-experience

I want to create an animated [side navigation menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp).

The problem is that on opening and on closing the items "jump around" (only on menu items that consists of more than one word). How can I prevent this?

It really looks ugly like this. I want that the menu appears without layout jumps.

**EXAMPLE**

The following code is from w3schools. It's just for illustration purposes.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About Me</a>
  <a href="#">My Services</a>
  <a href="#">Best Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, instead of playing with the width, release it and push the box off the page and pull it back. Thus, the animation will look fluent and professional.

**Related CSS property:**

```
transform: translateX (...)
```

You can test the change in my snippet. I specified the changing points in the snippet. Good luck with.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  /* Changed */ width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  
  /* Added */ transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About Me</a>
  <a href="#">My Services</a>
  <a href="#">Best Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style = "transform: translateX(0)"; // Changed
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style = ""; // Changed
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the difference between an animation with `transform: translateX` and an animation with the `margin-left` (add negative margin). What is better and why?

Comment: `margin` has existed since older css versions. Although transform is not very new, it is new to `margin`.
However, `margin` also affects other elements of the element. But `transform` does not affect other elements. So you don't need to set the element to `absolute` or `fixed` to apply `transform`. Which one should be preferred depends on the situation. But in examples like yours, `transform` is usually used.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: you can use the `white-space: nowrap` property.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; /* <- */
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About Me</a>
  <a href="#">My Services</a>
  <a href="#">Best Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```